# Dynamically Pass the Location and File name for the Create Database script

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to add the new file group and file into existing database.

My script:

```
DECLARE @AlterDB NVarchar(4000),
        @FGName NVarchar(30) = 'Partition_DW2_',
        @FileLoc NVarchar(50) ='D:\Data\',
        @CurrentYR NVarchar(10) ='2014' ,
        @FullName Nvarchar(max) 
 Set @FullName = @FileLoc+@FGName+@CurrentYR+'.ndf'
        Print @fullName
et @AlterDB = 'ALTER DATABASE Partition_DWJ2
                        ADD FILE 
                        (   NAME =  '+@FGName+@CurrentYR+',FILENAME ='+@FullName +',SIZE = 2048KB ,MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED,FILEGROWTH = 1024KB
                        )TO FILEGROUP '+@FGName+@CurrentYR

            EXECUTE SP_Executesql @AlterDB ,N'@FullName NVarchar(max)',@FullName=@FullName
            Print @ALterDB
```

This gives the error `'Incorrect syntax near 'D:'.'`

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, assuming that you are actually using `Set @AlterDB` instead of `et @AlterDB` on your script, you need to enclose the filename on single quotes:

```
DECLARE @AlterDB NVarchar(4000),
        @FGName NVarchar(30) = 'Partition_DW2_',
        @FileLoc NVarchar(50) ='D:\Data\',
        @CurrentYR NVarchar(10) ='2014' ,
        @FullName Nvarchar(max) 
 Set @FullName = @FileLoc+@FGName+@CurrentYR+'.ndf'
        Print @fullName
 Set @AlterDB = 'ALTER DATABASE Partition_DWJ2
                        ADD FILE 
                        (   NAME =  '+@FGName+@CurrentYR+',FILENAME ='+CHAR(39)+@FullName+CHAR(39)+',SIZE = 2048KB ,MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED,FILEGROWTH = 1024KB
                        )TO FILEGROUP '+@FGName+@CurrentYR

            EXECUTE SP_Executesql @AlterDB ,N'@FullName NVarchar(max)',@FullName=@FullName
            Print @ALterDB
```

Comment: why are you adding `Partition_DWJetblue2_`?

Comment: @JohnRiselvato Because that was the name op was using when I answered

Answer (score 0):

Try adding another backslash to your `@FileLoc NVarchar(50) = 'D:\\Data\\'`